# Open GL SDL Keypresses and behaviours mismatched on program start

Tags: opengl, input, keyboard, sdl

I'm developing a simple game in OpenGL and using the SDL library to handle my input.

The game uses several keyboard buttons for input. Two arrow keys, the space bar, the 'r' button to reset the game and escape to close it.

What's currently happening is that the output or the methods being called when these buttons are pressed when I first launch the game are mismatched. (i.e left arrow performs the right arrow's method). This random behaviour ends once I press each of the buttons the game uses apart from the escape button once.

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing as it feels like I have to 'assign' each button on each launch of the game. I've provided my input handling code below.

```
        if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                m_isClosed = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE:
                m_selection = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                m_leftPressed = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                m_rightPressed = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_r:
                m_reset = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(e.type == SDL_KEYUP)
            switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                m_leftPressed = false;
                m_keydown = false;
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                m_rightPressed = false;
                m_keydown = false;
                break;
            case SDLK_SPACE: 
                m_selection = false;
                m_keydown = false;
                break;
            case SDLK_r:
                m_reset = false;
                m_keydown = false;
                break;
            }
    }
```

Each event handler simply sets a boolean used for the game logic in another class. If you think you need to see anymore code in order to help me let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had not initialised the booleans corresponding to the button listeners to false. A silly mistake but I thought I should provide the solution nonetheless.